# select_related and prefetch_related - not getting results in query

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to make simple learning project where i am getting all records and displaying on html. 
My models are :

```
class Student(models.Model):
 stuName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 stuCity = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 stuPhone = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
 stuNationality = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 stuCreatedt = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
 def __str__(self):
     return '%s %s %s' % (self.stuName,self.stuCity,self.stuNationality)


class Dept(models.Model):
 deptId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 deptName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 def __str__(self):
      return '%s %s' % (self.deptId, self.deptName)




class Course(models.Model):
 courseId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 courseName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 enrolledStu = models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
 students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
 dept = models.ForeignKey(Dept, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 def __str__(self):
      return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.courseName,self.enrolledStu,self.students,self.dept)
```

from this model i am trying to display student , course and dept information using below query :

```
course = Course.objects.all().prefetch_related('students').select_related('dept')
```

my html code is :

```
{% for c in course %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{c.students.stuName}}</td>
        <td>{{c.students.stuCity}}</td>
        <td>{{c.dept.deptName}}</td>
        <td>{{c.courseName}}</td>
        <td><a href="#">Edit</a> </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I am unable to display student information.. Can any one please help me to correct my mistakes.I am assuming my query is not correct.

Jordan

Comment: Can you show what you are getting in `course`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `students` is many to many field and contain list of students you need to iterate over `students.all` to get students info:

```
{% for c in course %}
    <tr>
        {% for student in c.students.all %} 
            <td>{{student.stuName}}</td>
            <td>{{student.stuCity}}</td>
        {% endfor %} 
        <td>{{c.dept.deptName}}</td>
        <td>{{c.courseName}}</td>
        <td><a href="#">Edit</a> </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each course, you could display unique details about a course then display the enrolled students in a table below...

```
{% for c in course %}
    <p>{{c.dept.deptName}}</p>
    <p>{{c.courseName}}</p>
    <p><a href="#">Edit</a> </p>

    {% for s in c.students.all %}
    <tr> 
        <td>{{s.stuName}}</td>
        <td>{{s.stuCity}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```